# JQuery contains not working multiple li

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I´m trying to detect if an element it´s already appended into the DOM using $contains

var isAlreadyAppended = function (key) {

```
    return ($.contains($('#allBellMessageId'), $("#" + key)));
};

var test= function(){
   if(!isRepeated('a')){
       //Append into DOM
   };
       if(!isRepeated('b')){
       //Append into DOM
   };
       if(!isRepeated('c')){
       //Append into DOM
   };
    if(!isRepeated('a')){
       //Append into DOM
   };
}
```

And adding the keys, a,b,c,a still is returning false, false, false, false.

And the html code generated is this one

```
  <li id="bellMessagesId" class="dropdown notifications">
 <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
  <ul id="allBellMessageId" class="dropdown-menu bellMessage-dropdown-menu">
   <div class="col-xs-12">
  <li id="a" class="col-xs-12">
  <li id="b" class="col-xs-12">
  <li id="c" class="col-xs-12">
  <li id="a" class="col-xs-12">
  </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
```

And the render is 4 messages, a,b,c,a.

What I´m doing wrong?.

Regards.

Comment: By the way, your syntax is broken and you don't need semicolons after `if` statements.

Comment: I did not copy/paste the code, just add an example. I already correct the wrong syntax,

Comment: Your `if` statements are all invalid and you've not given any example of your DOM. Please take the time to create an actual demo of the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`isRepeated()`does not return anything, it just executes. Because its not returning anything, it will return `undefined`, so when you check it will say `undefined` and evaluate to `false`. So try this:

```
var isRepeated(key) = function(key){
  return $.contains($('#fooElements'), $("#" + key))
};
```

Apart from that, I'm not very familiar with `$.contains`, so you could try the following:

```
var isRepeated(key) = function(key){
  return $('#fooElements').find("#" + key).length ? true : false;
};
```

I use this all the time to check if something exists and it works like a charm.

Comment: Sorry the code that I wrote was not ok, in my code there´s returns. Like I said all falses

Comment: @paul I updated my answer with a method I use to check existence.

Answer (score 1):

[From jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.contains/)

The first argument of .contains() must be a DOM element, not a jQuery object or plain JavaScript object. Try running a loop and using

```
$.contains($('#fooElements')[i], $("#" + key)[0])
```

or something like that.

Comment: Wouldn't `$("#" + key)[0]` have to be `$("#" + key).get(0)`? Also, that would be a problem if you are looking for an element that doesn't exist as the `get` function wouldn't exist for a non-existing jquery object, and the array would be empty as well when the element does not exist.

Comment: @somethinghere it's pretty much the same thing.

Comment: @somethinghere: His answer is fine. Not sure what you mean about a non-existing jQuery object.

Comment: @gagik I'm pretty sure you can't use `[0]` on an empty array so this could error out. But hey, you are right about the DOM element thats needed so the method to get it is indeed irrelevant.

Comment: @somethinghere: Nope. `[][0] === undefined; // true`

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is one related to [Event Delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) if you're looking for elements that have been appended to the DOM.

Anything after the DOM is loaded is not registered. So if you're appending an element to something, you'll have to check its parent element first.

From the docs:

```
$( "#list" ).on( "click", "a", function( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log( $( this ).text() );
});
```

If the `<a>` tag was appended to the `#list` element, you first need to check the `#list` element and then check for the `a` tag.